# What's another word for "dreaming optimistic outcomes"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word that means dreaming too positively. This word can be symbolized for expecting too high.

Usage: "*(Present Participle of the word)* from the world would result in nothing but disappointment."

Comment: A present participle won't fit there. The best you can do is **a gerund with an object**, and that's what you already have in your question. ***Expecting too much** from the world would result in nothing but disappointment.*

Comment: A common term in English is "eternal optimism" or "eternal optimist," e.g. Eternal optimists are doomed to getting disappointed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Pipe-dreaming** [in] the world would result in nothing but disappointment.

**pipe-dream** (v.)

> *Intransitive*. To fantasize; to make unrealistic plans; to hope for the impossible.
>
> *When I asked him what the possibility was that he would switch, as the Hart forces hope, he replied as follows: ‘They are pipe-dreaming.’*
>
> C. Porter—*I'm Only wasting my time Pipe dreaming of you.* OED

**pipe dream** (n.)

> An illusory or fantastic plan, hope, or story [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pipe%20dream)

> A pipe dream is a hope or plan that you know will never really happen.
> [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/pipe-dream)

---

> She's just **pipe dreaming**, Hettie. And folks like you and Rocky
> shouldn't be talking all over town about how this is going to happen.
> People miss The Kismet's lights, but the theater is dead. [Hope
> Ramsay; *Last Chance Book Club*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Last_Chance_Book_Club/S5tKIlrN3_AC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22pipe%20dreaming%22&pg=PT45&printsec=frontcover) (2013)

> While Mine-Mill appealed to workers' appreciation of masculine
> toughness, USWA supporters countered with large ads urging workers to
> reject the irresponsible actions of the joint committee, who "after
> four months on strike are still **pipe dreaming** in Utopia." [Laurie
> Mercier; *Anaconda: Labor, Community, and Culture in Montana's Smelter
> City*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Anaconda/KTFNBFnYK9YC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22pipe%20dreaming%22%20disappoint&pg=PA174&printsec=frontcover)

> Elaborate inspection and certification mechanisms were made acceptable
> on the promise of higher prices in more stable markets, but this hope
> was dashed by price-sensitive buyers, and higher prices became a
> **pipe dream**.  [Eberhard Bruenig; *Conservation and Management of Tropical Rainforests*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Conservation_and_Management_of_Tropical/U6ksDgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22pipe%20dream%22%20hopes%20dashed&pg=PA280&printsec=frontcover)

Answer (score 0):

There are few words for your reference, such as "[Optimism bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimism_bias)", "[Over-optimistic](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/over-optimistic)" "[Starry-eyed](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/starry-eyed) ",  & "[Rose-colored-glasses](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/rose-colored-glasses?q=rose-colored)".

Comment: It strikes me that only "optimism bias" would work here, but it is not idiomatic. The other problem is that the example *"(Present Participle of the word) from the world would result in nothing but disappointment."* asks for a present participle and that will also result in an unidiomatic sentence.